# How to reopen a fragment with saved instance from another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 1 activity with multiple fragments. These fragments call each other, for example fragment a calls fragment b:

Fragment a:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new FragmentB());
ft.commit();
```

Where `OrderAddFragment` is fragment b.

Now, let's say a user has filled in multiple inputs in fragment a and continues to fragment b but than he realises he made a mistake in fragment a and needs to go back to correct this mistake.

How could I reopen fragment a with the saved instance state instead of creating a new instance?

The back function in fragment b uses following code to reopen fragment a:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new FragmentA());
ft.commit();
```

Comment: `ft.addToBackStack(null)` before commit from A to B, and calling `getActivity().onBackPressed()` to navigate back.

Comment: After adding it to the backstack, how would I get the fragment back?

Comment: calling getActivity().onBackPressed() to navigate back. – EpicPandaForce 11 mins ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FragmentTransaction.addToBackStack()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)) might solve your problem.

Comment: How do I implement this? After having the fragment added to the backstack, how do I reopen it from the other fragment?

Comment: Thankyou, I got it working by using `popBackTrace()` to close.